# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate on Android, Mostly Amazon S3

Tags: java, android, ssl, amazon-s3

As the title suggests I am intermittently seeing the "No peer certificate" error in our logs. I cannot replicate this locally and it is puzzling me as to what is occurring on the device to cause this. Note that it is intermittent - sometimes it happens to the user, sometimes it does not.

It seems to mostly occur when trying to upload to Amazon S3, but occasionally when attempting to hit our servers for authentication or other services. We are using HttpClient on Android (not the new URLConnection). I hate to spend a lot of time switching over (it would be a lot of work) and find out the issue is something else.

The error seems to happen to some users more than others and the frequency is not that high overall. Some 20 users were affected (out of thousands of users with many thousands of requests) over a 7 day period.

I have looked at other similar posts, but most were consistently happening or want you to turn off SSL trust, which I would rather not do. Perhaps someone will spot something with this code that is suspect (a similar pattern is used throughout the code base). Note I have gutted some code to make it more readable:

```
private static int TIMEOUT = 600000; // 10 minutes

public void mediaAmazonUploadFile(JSONObject authParams,  String formMediaDirectory, String filename, boolean publicRead) {
    String url = "";
    String accessKey = "";
    String policy = "";
    String signature = "";
    String contentType = "";
    String key = filename;
    String acl = "private";

    url = authParams.optString("mediaUrl");
    accessKey = authParams.optString("mediaAccessKey");
    policy = authParams.optString("mediaPolicy");
    signature = authParams.optString("mediaSignature");
    contentType = authParams.optString("contentType");

    if (publicRead)
        acl = "public";

    File file = new File(formMediaDirectory, filename);
    if (file.exists()) {

        // Try 2 times to send the file if failure. Hold connection 7 secs and socket 7 secs
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, TIMEOUT);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler retryhandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(RETRIES, true);
        httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryhandler);

        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);  
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        try {
            entity.addPart("AWSAccessKeyId", new StringBody(accessKey));
            entity.addPart("Content-Type", new StringBody(contentType));
            entity.addPart("policy", new StringBody(policy));
            entity.addPart("key", new StringBody(key));
            entity.addPart("acl", new StringBody(acl));
            entity.addPart("signature", new StringBody(signature));
            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
            postMethod.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
        } 
        catch (HttpResponseException re) {
            Utilities.logException(re);
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            Utilities.logException(cpe);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Utilities.logException(e);
        }
    }
    else {
        Utilities.logError("mediaAmazonUploadFile(), file not created ");
    }
}r
```